# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, uuid

```
import uuid from 'uuid';


class Courses {
    constructor(title, price, img) {
        this.title = title
        this.price = price
        this.img = img
        this.id = uuid.v4()
    }

    save(){

    }
}
```

терминал выдает ошибку

```
C:\Users\Kamran\Desktop\node-express\models\courses.js:1
import uuid from 'uuid';
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/676353

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/node @babel/preset-env`

Comment: установил все та же ошибка

Comment: тогда используйте requires

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Comment: суть когда использую, requires выводит C:\Users\Kamran\Desktop\node-express\node_modules\uuid\dist\esm-browser\index.js:1
export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: я так понял ошибка в самом uuid?

Comment: Я в ноде не шарю, но в uuid вряд ли ошибка.

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема, работает только на четных версиях node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в чем проблема, работает только на четных версиях node

Comment: нет в самой https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid написано

Comment: @LokiLoki, а где там это написано?

Comment: @Grundy, Cross-platform - Support for ...
CommonJS, ECMAScript Modules and CDN builds
**Node 8, 10, 12, 14**
Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge, IE 11 browsers
Webpack and rollup.js module bundlers
React Native

Comment: @LokiLoki, вообще выглядит, как будто там не это имелось ввиду

Comment: @Grundy, я то же так понял, просто на англо язычном форуме нашел, что это имеется ввиду ))))

Comment: Добавь ссылку и цитату в ответ

Comment: я уже не найду где прочитал